# SLRE regular expression won't work

Tags: c, regex

I am using the SLRE (https://code.google.com/p/slre/)

I am checking 15 strings with different regular expressions in that way:

```
struct slre        slre;
struct cap         captures[4 + 1];
int i = 0;
int numberOfSettings = 15;   
for (i; i < numberOfSettings; i++) { 
    if (!slre_compile(&slre, settings[i].regex)) {
        printf("Error compiling RE: %s\n", slre.err_str);
    }
    else if (!slre_match(&slre, settings[i].value, strlen(settings[i].value), captures)) {
        printf("\nSetting '%s' does not match the regular expression!", settings[i].internName);
    }
}
```

The regular expression I am using (`settings[i].regex`) for parsing an IP-address is:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

The value for checking (`settings[i].value`) is `8.8.8.8`

I am using the same regular expressions also with javascript and they are working as intended.

Does anyone have an idea why this would return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLRE doesn't support `|` - see the "Supported syntax" section in [slre.h](https://code.google.com/p/slre/source/browse/slre.h).

(Unless you have a specific reason not to, I'd recommend using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).)

Comment: Lol, I could have found out that too... ^^ Thanks! Btw I used the system library regex.h now.