# Is it possible to avoid using branch metachar in xsd pattern regex?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I'm pretty much novice to the world of regex, So here's my question:

Consider the following XSD snippet (EX1):

```
<restriction base=”token”>
<pattern value=”abc|xyz” />
</restriction>
```

Now, Consider i will replace it with the following code (EX2):

```
<restriction base=”token”>
<pattern value=”abc” />
<pattern value=”xyz” />
</restriction>
```

From what i know, the text in EX2 should match at least one of the patterns provided.
So, basically, it seems logically equal.

Now, for a personal-technical reason i'm trying to eliminate all '|' characters from my XSD code.
   Note: I know this character is also used for conditional regex's as an "else" keyword - I'm not using that.

Question is, except the conditional regex's, or the case i provided an example of above , Are there any other "use cases" for the '|' (branch) meta-char i should expect to encounter in the future while "expanding" my regex's ?

Thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to eliminate all `|` characters from my XSD code" - you could simply replace them all with `&#x7C;`.

Comment: Do you care that they (the `|`) could be used as literals? For example in `[a-z|&%]` or `/abc\|xyz/` etc… How do you intend to handle those situations?

Comment: Well, the main reason i asked my question was - i was about to use a library to parse the regex'es provided by "pattern" tag.  I chose SLRE as a solution.
Problem was, i saw here that SLRE doesn't support '|' meta-char:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616684/slre-regular-expression-wont-work

That is why i thought about finding a way to "force" the xsd to not use the '|' while still keeping the same logic.